# Call a function from outputted JS in HTML <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="test-div"></div>
<button class="a-button">Click</button>
```

Here is my JS/jQuery:

```
function parent() {

    alert("Parent");

    var output = "";

    output += "<p>Hello World</p>"
    output += "<script>$('.a-button').click(function() { parent(); });</script>"

    $("#test-div").html(output);
}

parent();
```

When I run this code and click on the button with class '.a-button' I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: parent is not a function
```

However, when I get rid of the HTML/Script output and put the click event outside of the parent function like so:

```
function parent() {

    alert("Parent");

    var output = "";

    output += "<p>Hello World</p>"
    //output += "<script>$('.a-button').click(function() { parent(); });</script>"

    $("#test-div").html(output);
}

parent();

$('.a-button').click(function() { 
    parent(); 
});
```

Everything works as expected.

Unfortunately though, this will not do as I need to be able to call the parent function from the outputted script.

I have tried to set up a Plunkr/JSFiddle for this problem but it seems neither supports the jQuery .html(output). All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not a good approach, can you explain why you need that? I bet there are many other ways to do that.

Comment: The outputted JS makes use of variables defined in a for loop. In actual fact, this script is outputted numerous times and each time it is slightly different with different ids related to the database. I went with the .html(output) option which seems to be working fine for me apart from this obvious issue!

Comment: _“In actual fact, this script is outputted numerous times and each time it is slightly different with different ids related to the database”_ – if you need the same function to run, only with different data each time, then you should probably put that data somewhere else – f.e. into a _custom data attribute_ on the element that will call the function when it is clicked. Outputting basically the same function code over and over again is rather nonsense.

Comment: I shall have a look at the custom data attribute but at this moment in time this is the only way I can work out what I need to achieve. A solution to the problem I have posted would be appreciated.

Comment: To be frank the easiest solution to your problem is what CBroe suggested. You might get your current approach to work with some effort but it would probably take a lot longer than doing it correctly.